# Some tomcat metrics disappeared in new spring-boot-starter-actuator version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot-actuator

I upgraded spring-boot-starter-actuator version to 2.7.0
and some chapters of tomcat metrics are missing now in MetricsEndpoint, such as:

```
tomcat.cache.access
tomcat.cache.hit
tomcat.global.error
etc.
```

How can I get them now?

Answer (score 2):

Need to add

> server.tomcat.mbeanregistry.enabled=true

in application.properties